# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null - its supposed to be null (sometimes), how to handle correctly?

Tags: php, fatal-error, symfony-2.8

Sometimes the expected result should be null, other times it's not (if it's not null, I want code function x to parse. If not null, code y parses).. not sure how to handle this appropriately:

```
$myID = is_object($widget->getParent()->getId()) ? $widget->getParent()->getId() : '';

if (isset($myID)){
//....code here
```

Result:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on null in \htdocs\program\widget\Controller\WidgetController.php on line 212
```

Line 212:

```
$myID = is_object($widget->getParent()->getId()) ? $widget->getParent()->getId() : '';
```

I've also tried variations of:
    `is_object()`
    `is_array()`
    `null ==`
    `null !==`

None seem to allow the code to process as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like $widget->getParent() is returning null maybe store that and check it first? I'd guess that getParent() might return null on a root element.

```
$myParent = widget->getParent();
if($myParent){
  $myID = is_object($myParent->getId()) ? $myParent->getId() : '';
  if (isset($myID)){
       //....code here
  }
} else {
  // Error handling
}
```

Comment: Also does getId() return an object? - This might be the next issue you run into if not.

Comment: Spot on my friend, this worked. getParent() was indeed sending an empty reply, yet the PHP errors kept pointing me to getID (it went right over my head, never thought to look at getParent()). Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad I could be of assistance :)